# Error compiling mix in laravel with cross-env ^ 7.0 and webpack 5.4 with custom mix file env argument

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

**Error:** Cannot find module webpack.mix while using npm to run dev with webpack ^5.42.0 to compile script with custom mix file, dev script is:

```
"dev-jsAlien": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --env.mixfile=webpack.mix.alien"
```

The above script works with webpack ^4.46.0

**npm error dump**

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --env.mixfile=webpack.mix.alien

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/webpack.mix'
Require stack:
- /Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
- /Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js
- /Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at module.exports (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:8:5)
    at handleFunction (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/prepareOptions.js:21:13)
    at prepareOptions (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    at requireConfig (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:117:14)
    at /Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at /Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
    at /Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at runCli (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:69:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/User/Sites/mdmc-orignal/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:162:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: What version of mix are you using? Newer versions use different scripts

Comment: Laravel-mix v6.0.25

Comment: Please read https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade

Comment: I have gone through the Laravel-mix 6 upgrade wiki, it didn't provide any signinficant information regarding using --env.mixfile or any other argument.

Comment: re install "composer require laravel/ui" after composer update

Comment: The significant bit is change the old style of `cross-env...` scripts to the new style of just `mix`

Comment: Post your package.json file.